# Not able to pass lead id from lightning helper to apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

lightining cmp--

---

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable" access="global" controller="LeadFunctionalLogDisplayHelper">
<!-- Initial handler, runs every time this component is loaded.-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<!-- Holds the Record Id for the lead.-->
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>

<!-- Holds the lead status-->
<aura:attribute name="leadStatus" type="Boolean"/>

<aura:attribute name="logNotEmpty" type="Boolean"/>

<aura:attribute name="log" type="String"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.leadStatus}">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.logNotEmpty}">
        <div class="logDiv">
            <ui:outputText value="{!v.log}"></ui:outputText>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:if>
```

---

controller

```
({ doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
      helper.initLead(component);
      helper.getEmptyLog(component);
      helper.getFunctionalLog(component); 
      helper.getLeadStatusHelper(component);
  }
 })
```

---

Helper

```
({
    initLead : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.initLead");
        action.setParams({
            id: cmp.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() == "ERROR"){
                $A.log(response.getError());
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    getLeadStatusHelper : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.leadStatusReturner");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                cmp.set("v.leadStatus", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    getEmptyLog : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.functionalLogEmpty");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.logNotEmpty", response.getReturnValue());
                console.log("component value: " + cmp.get("v.logNotEmpty"));
            } else if(response.getState() === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if(errors) {
                    if(errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    getFunctionalLog : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.functionalLogReturner");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log("Success: " + response.getReturnValue());
                cmp.set("v.log", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

---

Apex controller class

```
public with sharing class LeadFunctionalLogDisplayHelper {
    public static Lead currentLead{get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void initLead(Id id){
        System.debug('hello'+id);**///here i am getting null value**
        currentLead =[SELECT Id, FunctionalLog__c, Status
                        From Lead
                        WHERE Id =:id];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean functionalLogEmpty() {
        if(currentLead.FunctionalLog__c == null || currentLead.FunctionalLog__c == '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean leadStatusReturner() {
        if(currentLead.Status != CONSTANTS.LEAD_STATUS_UMAX && currentLead.Status != CONSTANTS.LEAD_STATUS_CANCELLED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String functionalLogReturner() {
        String returnString;
        if(functionalLogEmpty()){
            List<String> stringList = currentLead.FunctionalLog__c.split('\n');
            for(String s : stringList) {
                if(returnString != null) {
                    returnString = returnString + '- ' + s + '\n';
                } else {
                    returnString = '- ' + s + '\n';
                }
            }
        } else {
            returnString = '';
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the interface `force:hasRecordId` in your lightning component?

Comment: yes i implemented the interface

Comment: What is the URL of that lightning page ? force:hasRecord works only if it is in one.app container

Comment: force:hasRecordID IS WORKING FINE, but wile setting via setparam in  helper class i not able to set the recordid,and hence i am getting Attempt to reference null object in apex controller class

Answer (score 1):

Use unique names for client-side and server-side actions in a component. A JavaScript function (client-side action) with the same name as an Apex method (server-side action ) can lead to hard-to-debug issues. In debug mode, the framework logs a browser console warning about the clashing client-side and server-side action names.

You should rename apex method as

```
public static void initApexLead(Id id){
    System.debug('hello'+id);**///here i am getting null value**
    currentLead =[SELECT Id, FunctionalLog__c, Status
                       From Lead
                        WHERE Id =:id];
}
```

and helper method as

```
initLead : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.initApexLead");
        action.setParams({
            id: cmp.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() == "ERROR"){
                $A.log(response.getError());
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66880/discussion-on-answer-by-himanshu-not-able-to-pass-lead-id-from-lightning-helper).

Comment: I was using a parameter name of contactID on both client and server side , no errors or anything but the controller just received null as the value of the param.  Turned out, as suggested by this answer, changing the server side name to differ from the client side resolved my problem!  Thanks.